# How to use create-react-app on a RaspberryPi Zero nowadays?

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, raspberry-pi-zero

I want to create a **React** application on a **RaspberryPi Zero W**.

Nowadays, **create-react-app** require **NodeJs** version >= **14.x.x**.

I used to select builds that are present at https://nodejs.org/dist/ to install **NodeJs** on **RPZ**, but the compatible ones stop at version **11.x.x**.

I tried the followings :

- Use **create-react-app** with an older version *npx create-react-app@4 my-app* but this fails with log stating that global installations are no longer supported with older version than the current one.
- Install **CRA@4** locally and execute the **create-react-app** command from /node_modules/.bin but this throw the exact same error.
- Install a non-official **NodeJs** build among the ones present at https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/ and execute the latest version of **CRA** via **npx**. But these builds look unstable... With build **20.11.0** I got Internet disconnection error logs (but the connection is actually OK), and with build **14.21.3**, I got insufficient memory error logs, in both cases these errors happens when executing the **create-react-app** command, and make it fail.

**How to use create-react-app on a **RaspberryPi Zero** nowadays?**

Comment: Please check https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111130/how-to-install-nodejs-v12-on-raspi-zero-armv6-not-available-for-download-anymor

Comment: Thanks for the link but, as I said on the 3rd bullet point, I've tried to install unofficial builds, but the create-react-app command is failing with those

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Debian then you can install the latest Node.js with binaries from https://nodesource.com, then use npx to create a react website.

```bash
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_21.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ npx create-react-app my-app
$ cd my-app
$ npm start
```